# Angular 8 NgRx Effect in app.module is not a class

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to add NGRX effects in app.module

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      router: routerReducer
    }, {metaReducers}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 5
    }),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      serializer: MySerializer
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([EffectService])
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is giving error as `Class EffectsRootModule is not an Angular module`.

Need some help.

thanks

Comment: Did you install `@ngrx/effects` package?

Comment: How do you define your effect class ?